# Vaadin InvientCharts formatterJsFunc

Tags: charts, vaadin

I'm using a vaadin add-on for displaying some charts and I have such method available : 
setFormatterJsFunc and I'm not sure what kind of variables would be available to it .

Has anyone encountered this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's input is a `javascript` function, that when you hover on a point in the chart, it shows the value at there.

For example;

```
tooltip.setFormatterJsFunc("function() {"
            + " return '' + this.series.name +': '+ this.y +''; " + "}");
```